# Page with page template not using template in Preview

Tags: pages, templates, previews

I am using a page template created by myself, which is showing and working correctly in page backend. It also works on the front end.

The problem: Preview shows the normal "page.php" instead of using the template page. 
Any idea why this happens? I have never had this problem before. 
The template is called "page_temp_news.php" and is setup correctly and working so far.

Using latest wordpress 4.2.2.
nginx server.

Thank you!

AD

Comment: Post your template. Note: use hyphens in template names, not underscores

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I am using WordPress 4.6.1 and created 2 custom page templates with hyphens.  for some reason when I am in the editor and try to switch back and forth between my custom page templates for a specific page, the preview button does not show me what I switched too.  I have to click the update button in order to see the alternative template.